# Totally remove row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

In my VBA macro, I need to totally remove some rows. The following code deletes all the values in the rows - leaving blank, empty rows - but does not actually delete the rows. How do I do that?

```
    For i = UBound(DataArray) To LBound(DataArray) + 1 Step -1
       Rows(DataArray(i, 1)).Delete
    Next i
```

TIA.

[image: Trying to remove empty rows shown here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be deleting rows (below screenshot of before & after running the code);

```
Sub code()

Dim DataArray(6 To 10) As String
For i = UBound(DataArray) To LBound(DataArray) + 1 Step -1
    Rows(i).Delete
Next i
    
End Sub
```

**Before running the above code;**

[image]

**After Running the code;** ID number 6,7,8,9 are deleted...

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same result as before, Sachin. Perhaps I didn't explain it as well as I should. I'll post a pic in my question.

Comment: What I understood was you wish delete the certain rows, not just the content of it... & I'm guessing from your shared pic that row no. 68 & 69 supposed to be deleted, but even after running your code, just content of it is getting deleted... right ?

Comment: That's right. Only the values are gone. I'd like to remove the entire row.

Comment: @JoeLowery I've edited my answer... before & after running the code... you see, for me it seems to be deleting the rows... If it's still not working for you then maybe the issue is someplace else... as far as what I know... ".ClearContents" is the command responsible to deleting the values... ".delete" for deleting the cells...

Comment: Yup, your code works, Sachin - thanks. I was starting my new rows after those rows were deleted so it looked as if they were still there. Appreciate the response!